# Documentation on jQuery-UI widgets

Tags: jquery-ui

I have the following html:

```
<h3 class="accordion">My Accordion</h3>
<ul class="accordion">
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

And I've mocked up the behavior I want by doing the following:

```
$('h3.accordion').click(function() {
   $('h3.accordion+ul').toggle('slow');     
});
```

But I'd like to style it like the Theme Switcher widget found at [Admintasia](http://www.admintasia.com/live-demo/).
Admintasia uses classes like: ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all, ui-widget-header.

Q: Is there documentation on these widget classes, or am I to read the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of classes jQuery UI uses and what they're for can be found here:

http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/jQuery-UI-CSS-Framework